# How to use cron, PHP and MySQL code to delete records with multiple search terms

Tags: php, mysql, cron, records

I’m in a deep s**t and need help from smart fellows like you.

Here is some info about software and technologies I use: cPanel, Linux server, phpMyAdmin, MySQL.

I need to delete some records from a table on a daily basis. I do it normally by using **Select** statement on **phpMyAdmin** and then delete all the records.

*

```
Select `user_id` FROM `user`
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `user_id`
FROM `userinfo`
WHERE `essay` like '% yahoo %' AND user.user_id = userinfo.user_id)
```

*

The above code basically searches for specific words in **userinfo** table and displays their corresponding **user_id** in **user** table, which I then delete manually. In this particular case the search term is ‘**yahoo**’. I search for all the users who have the word ‘**yahoo**’ in their profile’s **essay** and delete them from user table.

The problem is I’ve got way too many search terms to do it manually.

I would love to have it written in php file and run through cron if it’s possible. Would be nice to have a field or fields on php file where I would type all possible search words/phrases then the code would execute all of them one after another.

I’ve heard it’s possible to use cron jobs for that, read some articles about them but have absolutely no idea how to handle it.

Your help would be much appreciated and please tell me if it’s unclear.
Regards,
Igor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should at least get you started. Keep in mind I don't know the structure of your DB so you may have to change some things. Also this is *by FAR* not the most efficient way to do it, but it is easy to follow, you can do this in a single MySQL query instead of looping  over each user id (which I show an *untested* example of see ---faster way---), but again I don't know about your DB structure so you'll have to play with it, plus this way does exactly what you do now, one at a time so hopefully it's easier to follow and you can mod it to be more efficient later. Backup your db before playing with this.

PHP script to do what you want:

```
<?php
//put your search terms in this array
$search_terms = array('yahoo', 'google', 'bing');

//conenct to your DB
$db_conn = mysql_connect('yourdbhost', 'yourdbuser', 'yourdbpassword');
mysql_select_db('yourdbname', $db_conn);

//query the db for each search term
foreach($search_terms as $search_term) {
    //----slow but clear way----    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id 
                        FROM user
                        WHERE EXISTS (
                            SELECT user_id
                            FROM userinfo
                            WHERE essay like '%{$search_term}%' 
                            AND user.user_id = userinfo.user_id)", $db_conn);

    //for eachr user id returned, delete them from your users table 
    //as you would have done manually. I don't know about your users
    //table so you will have to edit this query as you see fit.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $user_del_result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user 
                                        WHERE user_id = {$row['user_id']}
                                        LIMIT 1", $db_conn);
        //might want to check here to see if the query executed successfully
    }

    //----faster way----
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user
                            WHERE EXISTS (
                            SELECT user_id
                            FROM userinfo
                            WHERE essay like '%{$search_term}%' 
                            AND user.user_id = userinfo.user_id)", $db_conn);
}
?>
```

To call it periodically you need to have a look at cron jobs ([read this](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)) and then just call the PHP script periodically with something like this in your crontab (this would run once per day at midnight for instance):

```
0 0 * * *   /path/to/php-cli /path/to/the/above/php/file.php
```

Comment: BTW, you should be using the mysqli library for new code instead of mysql_* library calls, which is inefficient and insecure :)

Comment: thanks shannonman. sorry for my ignorance, where can I get more information about mysqli library in contrast to mysql_*? Your help would be really appreciated.
BTW, you should be using the mysqli library for new code instead of mysql_* library calls, which is inefficient and insecure :)

Comment: Hi shannonman, I'm trying to use your script for my cron jobs but having no luck at all. the problem might be with actual path to the script, which is   (* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/gofishda/public_html/_cron/-cron-user-userinfo.php)  I set it up to run every minute just to test but it's not running and there is even no email notification, which I've set up to notify me when the script runs. I'm not quite sure how to create the correct path. the one I've provided I copied from other cron tasks. if you know anything or can point me to some tutorials i would really appreciate. cheers

Answer (score 2):

Deep s**t is never a good place to be...

If you're set on using a PHP script, then you can do this using crontab. Perhaps, at it's most basic, your best bet is to write a PHP script that can be executed using cron:

```
<?php

  $DB_hostname = "localhost";
  $DB_name     = "someDB";
  $DB_username = "someUser";
  $DB_password = "guessmeifyoucan";

  $connection = mysql_connect($DB_hostname, $DB_username, $DB_password) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($DB_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

  $delete_query = "DELETE from `user`
                   WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT `user_id` FROM `userinfo`
                   WHERE `essay` like '%yahoo%' AND user.user_id = userinfo.user_id)";

  $result = mysql_query($delete_query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

For the sake of sanity, I would however suggest logging any deletions to a file or using a live/dead flag in your DB. Wildcard string matches are dangerous and you may be better off using a DB flag (either live/dead or '0'/'1') - unless there is no need for comeback.

You could then set and execute this using the crontab. cPanel provides the ability to run cron scripts, but you can also achieve the same using CLI/shell:

1.`crontab -e` (using your editor of choice)
2. set `0 6 * * * php /path/to/script.php` (for 6:00am daily)

The following format is used within the crontab (presuming you're using some flavour of linux):

```
Minutes [0-59]
|   Hours [0-23]
|   |   Days [1-31]
|   |   |   Months [1-12]
|   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]
|   |   |   |   |
*   *   *   *   * php /path/to/script.php
```

There are other commands, options and outputs, but this is the most basic implementation. You can find further more detailed cron usage [here](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/cron/).

You can also do this using a query.sql file if needs be and executing it using MySQL on the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose you are using the script I don't think you even need to use PHP. If I had to do something like this I would probably do the following:

Create a MySQL script `script.sql` as follows:

```
USE `database_name`;

DELETE A.* FROM `userinfo` A
INNER JOIN `user` B
ON A.user_id = B.user_id
AND (
    A.essay LIKE '% yahoo %'
    OR
    A.essay LIKE '% google %'
    OR
    A.essay LIKE '% microsoft %'
);
```

Then I would setup a cron job as follows:

- Open the shell and enter `crontab -e` to edit your cron file. This should open a `vi` editor instance (you should know how to use `vi`).
- Add a daily schedule entry to your cron file `0 2 * * *       mysql -u{user} -p{password} {db_name} < {path of script.sql}`. This will run your script daily at `2:00am`.
- Save the file and exit

Whenever you need to modify or add search terms just modify and use the line `A.essay LIKE '% microsoft %'` as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Change `select user_id from user` to be `delete from user` and leave the rest of the statement exactly the same.

Be sure to back up your users table before doing this..

Once you've verified that the SQL functions how you want it to, you need to write a small PHP script that sends that SQL to MySQL, and have cron run that script once per day.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to start off by creating a PHP Script that will connect to MySQL and do what you're wanting. After that you can then look into Crons and how they work. Essentially it will kick off a script for you on a specified cadence. cPanel has a special section that let's you scheduled Crons.